# FireStore Rules : getting a data from a node

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

i want to get the data from a document in my FireStore

to be able to change the Rules based on it

so i put in FireStore Rules

```
    function isPrem(){
    return get(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(request.auth.userId)/info/payment).data.paid;
 }
```

then

```
      match /databases/{database}/documents/faqs/{document=**}{
  allow read : if isPrem();
  }
```

and my node is like this

users > userId > info > payment > {paid this is the value that i want to get }

thank u

Answer (score 0):

solved it by adding

```
      match /databases/{database}/documents/faqs/{document=**}{
  allow read : if get(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(request.auth.uid)/info/payment).data.paid == true ;
  }
```

but i was trying to making it in an external function